# HAProxy loadbalanced backend - behaviour when one server down

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

My understanding was that with two server backends load-balanced by HAProxy , if one goes down, HAProxy should be able to direct all traffic to the other.

I have two loadbalaced webservers, with roundrobin and httpchk, but when one goes down I get `503 - Service unavailable` messages from HAProxy.  Perhaps there is something wrong with my config?

```
backend app
    timeout server 50000ms
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk

    server ap1 ap1:8000 maxconn 4000 #ap1 is hostname
    server ap2 ap2:8000 maxconn 4000 #ap2 is hostname
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it helps if you add an explicit URL to your httpchk - per default it uses an http OPTION on /. Also you have to add the "check" keyword to your host definitions (http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/haproxy-en.txt section 3.1)

```
backend app
    timeout server 50000ms
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD /some/valid/url

    server ap1 ap1:8000 maxconn 4000 check #ap1 is hostname
    server ap2 ap2:8000 maxconn 4000 check #ap2 is hostname
```

Comment: Ah - missed the `check`.  I'll add that and see (the default url should be ok, but I've explicitly added one now anyway).  Thank you.